# Text fields for array dynamically created by Jquery submits first entry only

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with inputs for an array column on my DB.  I am loading a new INPUT field on click of a button with Jquery and setting it's name attribute & ID value manually to work with the form.  When I submit the form to the Controller, the original input field (not generated by Jquery) is the only value that gets saved.

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column guest_input_fields_wrap w-100">
  <div class="d-flex pb-2 align-items-baseline">
    <input placeholder="e.g. Sunscreen" type="text" multiple="true" name="experience_adventure[guest_bring][]" id="experience_adventure_guest_bring_1">
      <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
  var guest_wrapper         = $(".guest_input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var guest_add_button      = $(".new_guest_item"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(guest_add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(guest_wrapper).append('<div class="d-flex pb-2 align-items-baseline"><input placeholder="e.g. Sunscreen" type="text" name="experience_adventure[guest_bring][]" id="experience_adventure_guest_bring_' + x + '" multiple="true" style="box-shadow:none;"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(guest_wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
  })
```

If I write out the input in HTML instead of injecting with Jquery, the form works fine and sends both inputs to the array column.

```
<input placeholder="e.g. Sunscreen" type="text" multiple="true" name="experience_adventure[guest_bring][]" id="experience_adventure_guest_bring_1">
```

I expect that the form would send the array with all entries to the controller, but instead it only sends the first.

TERMINAL RESPONSE ("Item 1" is entered text on form)

```
["guest_bring", "{\"Item 1\"}"]
```

EXPECTED RESPONSE

```
["guest_bring", "{Item 1, Item 2, Item 3}"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a lot simpler of an answer than I had expected :).  I found a blog post here: https://sanjusoftware.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/dynamically-added-fields-using-ajax-do-not-get-posted-on-form-submission-form-inside-table/

This gave me some insights into my HTML markup and where my form tags start/end.  I realized that my form tags did not encompass all the body of the form partial on the page.  When I moved the start/end tags to encompass the entire HTML of the __form partial, it worked started working perfectly.